# Allow some basic HTML formating inside query results or interpret MarkDown

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, data-explorer, sql

I wrote this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/193616) and Markdown inside third column wasn't converted to HTML. So I converted the closes reasons to HTML and it appears that the Javascript doesn't make the rows look parsed.

As there is no sanitizing code or tag like`<xmp></xmp>`for that part ***and the HTML is not escaped at all*** inside the code HTML code. I don't think the current behaviour was completely intentional.

If you still don't understand just take a look at the third column of this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/193616) where close reasons appears like this:

> `Questions seeking debugging help ("<b>why isn't this code working?</b>") must include the desired behavior, a <i>specific problem or error</i> and <i>the shortest code necessary</i> to reproduce it <b>in the question itself</b>`

Expected behaviour:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**

Comment: @Yes : When row contains HTML it is printed as text, but there is no HTML tag like`<pre>` and the row are pure JavaScript generated *(and indeed it is impossible to get the non raw text result of a query without JavaScript)*.

Answer (score 4):

I would say this behaviour is entirely intentional. The data explorer gives you a view into the data in the database. It's not an HTML parser, a display engine, or anything of the kind.

You're welcome to do whatever you want with that data, though, so feel free to post-process the results however you see fit.

Comment: Intention confirmed, and I don't see a compelling reason to change it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you would expect to have rendered HTML in the table of results. Consider that the results of the query can include complete HTML source of posts: paragraphs, lists, headings etc. Rendering all this in a table with up to 50000 rows would be crazy. You would not want to be scrolling a page with 50000 SE posts in it.

The current behavior makes perfect sense to me. The output is a table, in which the cells are expected to contain *numbers* or *text*, not HTML. It is created with [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid). The script probably sets the `textContent` property of each cell, and therefore has no need to escape HTML.

I imagine it working like the following example on this question page:

```
document.querySelector('.post-text p').textContent = 'This is <b>not</b> going to be parsed as HTML';
```

[image: example]

Comment: Currently the system will never allow you to use more than 40,000 rows due to RAM limits. Triggering the rendering from the browser engine console only add a 1/2 min stall on my tablet. And as I said there is no`&amp`or`<xmp>…</xmp>`, it doesn’t look to be intentional as`textcontent`automatically escape tags which is not the case here. Of course a better alternative is to automatically convert MarkDown to HTML by the software rather than having to deal with it manually inside the query.

Comment: if you look at the page source, You’ll also see the HTML is not escaped.

Comment: It doesn't explains for MarkDown rendering.